# How do I organize function results within a for-loop?

Tags: python, for-loop

I have a list of file names to run through a processTestFile() function, which returns a dictionary of results that I'd like to store:

```
 # Count success or failure of test cases
  counts = {
    "success": 0,
    "failure": 0 
    }
```

The main process loop looks like this:

```
for fileName in all_files(fileReferences["testCasesPath"],"*.txt") :
    print "\n\nRunning test case file = ", fileName
    myCounts = processTestFile(fileName)
```

I was thinking of something like:

```
  myArray = {}
  myArray[fileName] = myCounts
```

and I would reference as:

```
for name in myArray
    print name, myArray[name] ["success"], myArray[name] ["failure"]
```

I doubt this code would work.  What do you advise?

Comment: Why do you doubt it would work? Did it fail? What is the error?

Comment: Please, read the [PEP 8 - Style Guide for Python Code](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)!

Comment: by modern I meant that I wanted to avoid using three arrays: one for the filename, second for success, and the third for failure.

Answer (score 1):

`myArray` is an odd name for a `dict`. Make sure you initialise it *outside* the loop

```
myArray = {}
for fileName in all_files(fileReferences["testCasesPath"], "*.txt"):
    print "\n\nRunning test case file = ", fileName
    myCounts = processTestFile(fileName)
    myArray[fileName] = myCounts

for name, value in myArray.items()
    print name, value["success"], value["failure"]
```

Comment: Good interpretation of the Q at hand. Adding for @historystamp, that you can assign the processTestFile() result directly to the myArray dict, and do away with the myCounts variable.

Comment: Thanks gnibbler. Good comment by wez. I am looking for the best way to implement this. This looks good. I guess since you access these collections with [], I think of them as arrays.

Comment: `for name, value in myArray.items():` # note trailing colon: